# execute linux commands in llvm pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc

Is there any way to execute linux commands in llvm pass and parse the objdump in it.

For example in python we can do as follows:

```
os.system('gcc example.c -o example') 
os.system('objdump -o example > parsed.txt')
```

and parse it by using regular expression.So, similarly can we do it in llvm pass as well?

Comment: You could call out to the system using any normal C/C++ system programming tools, but that would probably be considered "weird". What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @echristo - It's for my project, already I have an llvm pass, so I have to create another llvm pass so that I can call system () to execute the old llvm pass from the new llvm pass and then parse the object file of it.So can i use getAnalysisUsage() to do this?

Comment: You should just add you new pass to the pass pipeline like you did with your previous pass.